Как исправить 'Failed to look up the SID for username' при создании службы через NSSM?
Пробую добавить службу такой строкой
nssm install TotalCMD2 confirm && nssm set TotalCMD2 Application psexec64 && nssm set TotalCMD2 AppParameters -u User -p 555555 -i 1 %Commander_EXE% /i=%Commander_PATH%\WinCMD64.ini && nssm set TotalCMD2 Description Служба для запуска Total Commander при загрузке. && nssm set TotalCMD2 Start SERVICE_AUTO_START && nssm set TotalCMD2 ObjectName \\Domain\User Password && nssm set TotalCMD2 Type SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS && nssm set TotalCMD2 AppPriority ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS && nssm set TotalCMD2 AppNoConsole 1 && nssm set TotalCMD2 AppStopMethodSkip 1 && nssm set TotalCMD2 AppExit Exit

В ответ получаю:
Failed to look up the SID for username \\Domain\User!
LsaLookupNames(): Сопоставление между именами пользователей и идентификаторами безопасности не было произведено.

Как это исправить?
ПС. Если просто ввожу по документации на оф. сайте 'Object User Password', то:
ChangeServiceConfig(): Имя учетной записи задано неверно или не существует, или же неверен указанный пароль.

Error setting parameter "ObjectName" for service "TotalCMD2"!

